# merging .xlsx files into one without overwriting data

Tags: python, excel, pandas

```
import os

import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import filedialog

import pandas as pd

import xlrd

import openpyxl

from openpyxl import load_workbook

import datetime

from dataclasses import dataclass

from openpyxl.styles import Font,Color,Alignment,Border,Side,colors

import numpy as np

from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

import xlwt

from xlwt import Workbook

import functools

import numpy as np

from itertools import repeat, chain

import glob

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg = 'lightsteelblue')
canvas1.pack()

def getExcel():
    global df

    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

    df = pd.read_excel (import_file_path)

    del df['PART CODE']

    del df['SUPPLIER CODE']

    del df['COMPANY OR SUB-CONT']

    del df['SUB-CONT UNIT COST']

    del df['HLR']

    del df['HOURLY MULTIPLIER']

    del df['MATERIAL MULTIPLIER']

    del df ['ROUGH-IN HOURS']

    del df['FINISH HOURS']

    del df['PRELIMINARY TEXT']

    del df['FORMAL TEXT']

    del df['SUBCONT TEXT']

    del df['Part Image Path']

    df.insert(0,'Id','')

    df.insert(1,'M','M')

    df.insert(3,'SubCategory', '')

    df.insert(4,'DrillDowns', '')

    df.insert(6, 'Name', '')

    df = df.rename(columns={'PART UNIT TYPE': 'MeasurementType'})

    df.insert(8,'OnOffSwitch', 'No')

    df['SubCategory'] = df['CATEGORY']

    df = df.rename(columns={'PART DESCRIPTION': 'Note'})

    df['Name'] = df['Note']

    df = df.rename(columns={'COMPANY UNIT COST': 'PRICE'})

    new_row = pd.DataFrame({'Id':'(BLANK = NEW)', 'M':'P', 'CATEGORY':'Brand', 
                        'SubCategory':'Name', 'DrillDowns':'Price - Bathroom {nwPFGtikvZ}', 'Name':'Price - HVAC {cp7lAPx4IO}', 'Note': 'Price - XPS1 {qX8FFEVmqP}', 
                        'MeasurementType':'Price - PRIME {atGoZ7zLsE}', 'OnOffSwitch':'Price - ARCHIVE {NtbEEROpa9}', 'NeedToReplace':'Price - FLOORING {AskrHJL9ab}', 'NeedToReplace1':'Price - TEST {jOn0TaUDmU}', 'NeedToReplace2':'Price - Kitchen Refacing {9iFFUgrQBr}', 'NeedToReplace3':'Price - EAGLE EYES {X8ExSUDoFH}', 'NeedToReplace4':'Price - Basement {ajuemFbXaL}', 'NeedToReplace5': 'Price - Egress Windows {69790nzjKb}'}, 
                                                            index =[0]) 
    # simply concatenate both dataframes 
    df = pd.concat([new_row, df]).reset_index(drop = True) 
    df = df.fillna('')
    #new_row1 = pd.DataFrame({'Id':' ', 'M':'P', 'CATEGORY': 'SITE-PREP'}, index= [2])

    switches = df['M'].ne(df['M'].shift(16000))
    idx = switches[switches].index

    df_new = pd.DataFrame(index=idx + 1.5)
    df = pd.concat([df, df_new]).sort_index()

    #df = pd.concat([new_row1, df]).reset_index(drop = True)

    df = df.fillna('NO VALUE')
    df.M = df.M.replace({'NO VALUE': "P"})
    df.Id = df.Id.replace({'NO VALUE': ""})
    df.DrillDowns = df.DrillDowns.replace({'NO VALUE': "xxxx"})
    df.Name = df.Name.replace({'NO VALUE': "xxxx"})
    df.Note = df.Note.replace({'NO VALUE': "xxxx"})
    df.MeasurementType = df.MeasurementType.replace({'NO VALUE': "xxxx"})
    df.OnOffSwitch = df.OnOffSwitch.replace({'NO VALUE': "xxxx"})
    df.NeedToReplace = df.NeedToReplace.replace({'NO VALUE': "xxxx"})
    df.NeedToReplace1 = df.NeedToReplace1.replace({'NO VALUE': "xxxx"})
    df.NeedToReplace2 = df.NeedToReplace2.replace({'NO VALUE': "xxxx"})
    df.NeedToReplace3 = df.NeedToReplace3.replace({'NO VALUE': "xxxx"})
    df.NeedToReplace5 = df.NeedToReplace3.replace({'NO VALUE': "xxxx"})
    df['NeedToReplace4'] = df['PRICE'].shift(1)
    df = df.fillna("Price - Basement {ajuemFbXaL}")
    df.NeedToReplace4 = df.NeedToReplace4.replace({'NO VALUE': ""})
    del df['PRICE']
    df = df.rename(columns={'NeedToReplace': ''})
    df = df.rename(columns={'NeedToReplace1': ' '})
    df = df.rename(columns={'NeedToReplace2': '  '})
    df = df.rename(columns={'NeedToReplace3': '   '})
    df = df.rename(columns={'NeedToReplace4': '    '})
    df = df.rename(columns={'NeedToReplace5': '     '})

    df.CATEGORY.replace('NO VALUE',df.Note.shift(1),inplace=True)
    df.SubCategory.replace('NO VALUE',df.Name.shift(1),inplace=True)

    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)
    pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)



browseButton_Excel = tk.Button(text='Select Excel File', command=getExcel, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=browseButton_Excel)

root.mainloop()

df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\Larso\Desktop\ClearEstimatesEstimate\LeapPriceGuideExport.xlsx', sheet_name='Price Guide', index = False)

file1 = pd.read_excel("LeapPriceGuideExport.xlsx")
file2 = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")

file3 = file1.merge(file2, on="ID", how="outer")

file3.to_excel("merged.xlsx")
```

This is my current code above, im editing an excel file to go into an existing .xlsx file, but every time  i try to merge the files i get error code

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'LeapPriceGuideExport.xlsx'

i clearly see the file in the folder, but not sure what i am missing, thank you, and please let me know if things didnt come through clearly, i am stilling getting used to posting and asking questions, thank you.

Comment: tried the code below but got another error code
excel_names = ["test.xlsx", "test1.xlsx"]



excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]



frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], 

header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]



frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

# concatenate them..

combined = pd.concat(frames)

# write it out

combined.to_excel("test2.xlsx", header=False, index=False)

gives me error code

XLRDError: ZIP file contents not a known type of workbook

Comment: I thought this code looked familiar. Can you answer my [posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958456/concatenating-data-frame-adds-two-unneeded-columns#comment107848897_60958456) to you?

Comment: my apologies parfait, it was a spelling error on my part for that which was creating an extra column for me

Comment: Consider deleting that question then to avoid duplicates/unneeded open questions. Thanks.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in [r"C:\Users\Larso\Desktop\ClearEstimatesEstimate\test.xlsx", r"C:\Users\Larso\Desktop\ClearEstimatesEstimate\test1.xlsx"]:
    data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Price Guide')
    df = df.append(data)

df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df.to_excel('C://Users//Larso//Desktop//ClearEstimatesEstimate//results.xlsx', index=False)
found this code but it ends up splitting my test1 in the middle by 5 columns